# IDBKeyRange - openCursor vs get for retrieving the latest row

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I tend to query for the latest record by one of these two queries.

```
var range = IDBKeyRange.bound([1,0],[1,Date.now()]);
var article = db.transaction('article').objectStore('article').index('userid-date_created');

article.openCursor(range,'prev').onsuccess = function(e){
   var rowA = e.target.result.value;
};

//or
article.get(range).onsuccess = function(e){
    var rowB = e.target.result;
};
```

The `openCursor` approach obviously works but I have no idea about the `get` one.

Do the above queries output the same record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get query finds the first matching object. This is analogous to opening a cursor that moves forward, which happens when you do not specify a second argument to openCursor, or when you specify the 'next' parameter.

You opened a cursor with a second argument of 'prev', which starts at the last matching object and moves backward.

Obviously, the first and last object out of the set of matching objects are not the same object, unless there is only one matching object in total.

Comment: I should've washed my face before asking any questions like this.Thanks for your time.